# Searching for hidden API to scrape data with Python

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping

i've succesfully scraped data from this site:
https://football.goaloo2.com/subleague/2022-2023/40/261/?selectround=23

Now after some hints and some basic tutorials i'm trying to scrape it using hidden API...but on this site i got something different from others i was able to scrape. This is my process: with chrome i do inspection/network and then Fetch/XHR, reloadong the page i got what i thought it would be the call (even if the preview is different from other scraped sites, there's no three to navigate); than i copy as curl(cmd) and after pasting in converting site to python i obtained this:

```
import requests

params = {
    'sclassId': '40',
    'subSclassId': '261',
    'matchSeason': '2022-2023',
    'round': '23',
    'flesh': '0.6807624444063407',
}
response = requests.get('https://football.goaloo2.com/ajax/LeagueOddsAjax', params=params)


odds = response.json()
```

I got this error: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

I suspect data is not embedded in a json object, any idea on how to proceede if it is doable in python?

Comment: Thanks to both, i got the method even if i'm not used to regex, the problem is with this call there are all the odds but not matches: you need nother call to have different teams but pairing them with their respective odds seems very difficult to me (evey match has a correspnding number that is not present in the call that get the matchs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned object is not decodable JSON. You can take out the raw text and manipulate it into the JSON format. Then manually load it using json.loads() function. Note that, the web scrapping is not always standartized and you should check the stability of the manipulation. A very quick and dirty transformation as follows;

```
d = "{\"OddsData\": {" + response.text.replace('=', ':').replace(';', ',').replace('"]:', '":').replace('oddsData[', '').replace(',,\n', '}}')
json.loads(d)
```

It returns as follows;

```
{'OddsData': {'O_2247562': [[4, 2.9, 2.95, 2.6],
   [16, 3, 2.95, 2.2],
   [18, 2.78, 3.1, 2.53],
   [60, 2.9, 2.9, 2.6],
   [70, 3.1, 3, 2.4],
   [81, 2.9, 3, 2.63],
   [82, 2.7, 2.9, 2.45],
   [88, 2.8, 3, 2.55],
   [90, 2.9, 3.3, 2.33],
   [104, 2.85, 2.9, 2.6],
   [110, 3.05, 3.15, 2.45],
   [115, 2.9, 2.9, 2.6],
   [158, 2.9, 3.1, 2.45],
   [173, 2.8, 2.8, 2.55],
   [177, 3.02, 3.25, 2.57],
   [255, 2.7, 3.25, 2.5],
   [281, 2.9, 3.1, 2.38],
   [370, 2.55, 2.6, 2.35],
   [422, 2.75, 3.2, 2.5],
   [450, 2.85, 2.95, 2.6],
   [474, 2.8, 3.1, 2.49],
   [499, 2.74, 3.25, 2.47],
   [517, 2.78, 3.1, 2.53],
   [545, 2.74, 3.25, 2.47],
   [659, 2.7, 3.07, 2.46],
   [976, 2.8, 3.15, 2.5]],
  'L_2247562': [[3, 1.04, 0, 0.84],
   [8, 1.2, 0, 0.7],
   [12, 1.15, 0, 0.77],
   [14, 0.95, 0, 0.8],
   [17, 1.05, 0, 0.85],
   [19, 1.1, 0, 0.65],
   [22, 0.78, -0.25, 0.91],
   [23, 1.05, 0, 0.87],
   [24, 1.05, 0, 0.85],
   [31, 0.8, -0.25, 1.13],
   [35, 1.05, 0, 0.85],
   [42, 0.99, 0, 0.8]],
  'T_2247562': [[3, 1.05, 2.25, 0.81],
   [4, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [8, 1, 2.25, 0.85],
   [9, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [12, 1.05, 2.25, 0.83],
   [14, 1, 2.25, 0.78],
   [17, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [19, 1.3, 2.5, 0.55],
   [22, 0.87, 2.25, 0.78],
   [23, 1.06, 2.25, 0.84],
   [24, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [31, 1.05, 2.25, 0.85],
   [35, 1.09, 2.25, 0.81],
   [42, 1.04, 2.25, 0.76],
   [49, 1.25, 2.5, 0.57]],
  'O_2247563': [[4, 3, 3.1, 2.4],
   [16, 2.8, 2.7, 2.45],
   [18, 2.98, 3.05, 2.39],
   [60, 3, 3.05, 2.44],
   [70, 2.95, 2.85, 2.6],
   [81, 3.13, 3, 2.5],
   [82, 2.87, 2.9, 2.35],
   [88, 3, 3, 2.4],
   [90, 2.8, 3.1, 2.43],
   [104, 2.95, 3.05, 2.4],
   [110, 3, 3.05, 2.5],
   [115, 3, 3, 2.45],
   [158, 2.87, 3.1, 2.45],
   [173, 2.9, 2.9, 2.36],
   [177, 3.06, 2.98, 2.66],
   [255, 2.9, 3.2, 2.37],
   [281, 3, 3.1, 2.4],
   [370, 2.65, 2.75, 2.2],
   [422, 2.87, 3.1, 2.45],
   [450, 2.95, 3.05, 2.4],
   [474, 2.86, 2.95, 2.56],
   [499, 2.86, 3.2, 2.38],
   [517, 2.98, 3.05, 2.39],
   [545, 2.86, 3.2, 2.38],
   [659, 2.84, 3.08, 2.35],
   [976, 3, 3.15, 2.35]],
  'L_2247563': [[3, 0.79, -0.25, 1.09],
   [8, 0.73, -0.25, 1.15],
   [12, 0.75, -0.25, 1.18],
   [14, 0.78, -0.25, 1.08],
   [17, 0.8, -0.25, 1.11],
   [19, 1.05, 0, 0.7],
   [22, 0.64, -0.25, 1.11],
   [23, 0.8, -0.25, 1.13],
   [24, 0.8, -0.25, 1.11],
   [31, 1.07, 0, 0.85],
   [35, 0.8, -0.25, 1.11],
   [42, 0.75, -0.25, 1.05]],
  'T_2247563': [[3, 0.79, 2, 1.07],
   [4, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [8, 0.73, 2, 1.15],
   [9, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [12, 0.75, 2, 1.15],
   [14, 0.75, 2, 1.05],
   [17, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [19, 1.3, 2.5, 0.55],
   [22, 0.63, 2, 1.06],
   [23, 0.8, 2, 1.11],
   [24, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [31, 1.11, 2.25, 0.8],
   [35, 1.09, 2.25, 0.81],
   [42, 1.04, 2.25, 0.76],
   [49, 1.25, 2.5, 0.55]],
  'O_2247564': [[4, 2.4, 3, 3.1],
   [16, 2.1, 2.9, 3.3],
   [18, 2.17, 3.15, 3.25],
   [60, 2.45, 3, 3.05],
   [70, 2.05, 3.15, 3.65],
   [81, 2.3, 3.1, 3.4],
   [82, 2.2, 3, 3.1],
   [88, 2.2, 3.1, 3.25],
   [90, 2.03, 3.3, 3.5],
   [104, 2.45, 3, 3],
   [110, 2.15, 3.2, 3.6],
   [115, 2.4, 3, 3.1],
   [158, 2.15, 3.2, 3.4],
   [173, 2.37, 2.85, 2.95],
   [177, 2.18, 3.28, 3.64],
   [255, 2.25, 3.3, 3.1],
   [281, 2.1, 3.2, 3.4],
   [370, 2.2, 2.7, 2.7],
   [422, 2.2, 3.2, 3.25],
   [450, 2.41, 3, 3],
   [474, 2.17, 3.15, 3.3],
   [499, 2.23, 3.3, 3.05],
   [517, 2.25, 3.15, 3.15],
   [545, 2.23, 3.3, 3.05],
   [659, 2.28, 3.15, 2.9],
   [976, 2.3, 3.2, 3.05]],
  'L_2247564': [[3, 0.97, 0.25, 0.91],
   [8, 0.83, 0.25, 1.03],
   [12, 0.75, 0.25, 1.18],
   [14, 0.88, 0.25, 0.95],
   [17, 1.05, 0.25, 0.85],
   [19, 1.05, 0.5, 0.7],
   [22, 0.79, 0.25, 0.9],
   [23, 0.98, 0.25, 0.94],
   [24, 1.05, 0.25, 0.85],
   [31, 0.87, 0.25, 1.05],
   [35, 1.05, 0.25, 0.85],
   [42, 0.99, 0.25, 0.8]],
  'T_2247564': [[3, 0.98, 2.25, 0.88],
   [4, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [8, 1.03, 2.25, 0.83],
   [9, 1.2, 2.5, 0.62],
   [12, 1.05, 2.25, 0.83],
   [14, 0.95, 2.25, 0.88],
   [17, 0.98, 2.25, 0.9],
   [19, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [22, 0.91, 2.25, 0.74],
   [23, 0.99, 2.25, 0.91],
   [24, 0.98, 2.25, 0.9],
   [31, 1.05, 2.25, 0.85],
   [35, 0.99, 2.25, 0.91],
   [42, 0.93, 2.25, 0.85],
   [49, 1.15, 2.5, 0.62]],
  'O_2247565': [[4, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2],
   [16, 2.2, 2.9, 3],
   [18, 2.16, 3.2, 3.3],
   [60, 2.35, 3.05, 3.15],
   [70, 2.05, 3.15, 3.65],
   [81, 2.3, 3.1, 3.4],
   [82, 2.15, 3, 3.1],
   [88, 2.2, 3.1, 3.25],
   [90, 2.27, 3.2, 3.1],
   [104, 2.3, 3.1, 3.15],
   [110, 2.3, 3.15, 3.25],
   [115, 2.3, 3.1, 3.2],
   [158, 2.25, 3.3, 3.1],
   [173, 2.27, 2.9, 3.05],
   [177, 2.36, 3.07, 3.46],
   [255, 2.25, 3.3, 3.1],
   [281, 2.25, 3.2, 3.2],
   [370, 2.1, 2.75, 2.8],
   [422, 2.25, 3.3, 3.1],
   [450, 2.31, 3.05, 3.15],
   [474, 2.35, 3.15, 2.98],
   [499, 2.21, 3.3, 3.1],
   [517, 2.25, 3.2, 3.1],
   [545, 2.21, 3.3, 3.1],
   [659, 2.22, 3.15, 2.98],
   [976, 2.25, 3.2, 3.15]],
  'L_2247565': [[3, 0.95, 0.25, 0.93],
   [8, 0.98, 0.25, 0.88],
   [12, 1.02, 0.25, 0.88],
   [14, 0.91, 0.25, 0.91],
   [17, 1, 0.25, 0.9],
   [19, 0.6, 0, 1.2],
   [22, 0.91, 0.25, 0.78],
   [23, 0.96, 0.25, 0.96],
   [24, 1, 0.25, 0.9],
   [31, 1.02, 0.25, 0.9],
   [35, 1, 0.25, 0.9],
   [42, 0.94, 0.25, 0.84]],
  'T_2247565': [[3, 0.98, 2.25, 0.88],
   [4, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [8, 0.95, 2.25, 0.9],
   [9, 1.2, 2.5, 0.62],
   [12, 1.05, 2.25, 0.83],
   [14, 0.95, 2.25, 0.88],
   [17, 0.98, 2.25, 0.9],
   [19, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [22, 0.83, 2.25, 0.82],
   [23, 0.99, 2.25, 0.91],
   [24, 0.98, 2.25, 0.9],
   [31, 1, 2.25, 0.9],
   [35, 0.99, 2.25, 0.91],
   [42, 0.93, 2.25, 0.85],
   [49, 1.15, 2.5, 0.62]],
  'O_2247566': [[4, 1.9, 3.25, 4.2],
   [16, 1.8, 3, 4.3],
   [18, 1.95, 3.25, 3.85],
   [60, 1.95, 3.2, 4.1],
   [70, 1.87, 3.1, 4.5],
   [81, 1.95, 3.2, 4.2],
   [82, 1.87, 3.1, 3.9],
   [88, 1.91, 3.2, 4],
   [90, 1.92, 3.4, 3.7],
   [104, 1.95, 3.2, 4],
   [110, 1.9, 3.3, 4.25],
   [115, 1.91, 3.2, 4.2],
   [158, 1.93, 3.3, 3.9],
   [173, 1.89, 3.05, 3.95],
   [177, 1.88, 3.38, 4.96],
   [255, 1.93, 3.3, 3.9],
   [281, 1.91, 3.4, 4],
   [370, 1.75, 2.85, 3.5],
   [422, 1.93, 3.3, 3.9],
   [450, 1.92, 3.2, 4],
   [474, 1.96, 3.25, 3.8],
   [499, 1.94, 3.35, 3.75],
   [517, 1.95, 3.25, 3.85],
   [545, 1.94, 3.35, 3.75],
   [659, 1.89, 3.26, 3.75],
   [976, 1.9, 3.35, 4]],
  'L_2247566': [[3, 0.94, 0.5, 0.94],
   [8, 0.9, 0.5, 0.95],
   [12, 0.94, 0.5, 0.96],
   [14, 0.88, 0.5, 0.89],
   [17, 0.95, 0.5, 0.95],
   [19, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8],
   [22, 0.78, 0.5, 0.91],
   [23, 0.95, 0.5, 0.97],
   [24, 0.95, 0.5, 0.95],
   [31, 0.97, 0.5, 0.95],
   [35, 0.95, 0.5, 0.95],
   [42, 0.89, 0.5, 0.89]],
  'T_2247566': [[3, 0.98, 2.25, 0.88],
   [4, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [8, 0.98, 2.25, 0.88],
   [9, 1.2, 2.5, 0.62],
   [12, 1, 2.25, 0.88],
   [14, 0.93, 2.25, 0.85],
   [17, 0.98, 2.25, 0.9],
   [19, 1.1, 2.5, 0.65],
   [22, 1.09, 2.5, 0.62],
   [23, 0.99, 2.25, 0.91],
   [24, 0.98, 2.25, 0.9],
   [31, 1, 2.25, 0.9],
   [35, 0.99, 2.25, 0.91],
   [42, 0.93, 2.25, 0.85],
   [49, 1.15, 2.5, 0.62]],
  'O_2247567': [[4, 2.75, 2.95, 2.75],
   [16, 2.45, 3, 2.55],
   [18, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6],
   [60, 2.75, 2.9, 2.75],
   [70, 2.65, 3.05, 2.7],
   [81, 2.8, 3, 2.75],
   [82, 2.62, 2.9, 2.55],
   [88, 2.65, 3, 2.6],
   [90, 2.41, 3.4, 2.7],
   [104, 2.75, 2.9, 2.75],
   [110, 2.55, 3.15, 2.85],
   [115, 2.75, 2.9, 2.75],
   [158, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6],
   [173, 2.65, 2.8, 2.7],
   [177, 2.67, 3.3, 2.78],
   [255, 2.7, 2.9, 2.75],
   [281, 2.75, 3.1, 2.7],
   [370, 2.4, 2.65, 2.45],
   [422, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6],
   [450, 2.65, 3, 2.7],
   [474, 2.62, 3.1, 2.67],
   [499, 2.65, 3.25, 2.55],
   [517, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6],
   [545, 2.65, 3.25, 2.55],
   [659, 2.58, 3.07, 2.58],
   [976, 2.65, 3.1, 2.65]],
  'L_2247567': [[3, 0.98, 0, 0.9],
   [8, 0.9, 0, 0.95],
   [12, 0.84, 0, 1.06],
   [14, 0.91, 0, 0.85],
   [17, 0.95, 0, 0.95],
   [19, 0.8, 0, 0.9],
   [22, 0.81, 0, 0.88],
   [23, 0.99, 0, 0.93],
   [24, 0.95, 0, 0.95],
   [31, 0.94, 0, 0.98],
   [35, 0.95, 0, 0.95],
   [42, 0.89, 0, 0.89]],
  'T_2247567': [[3, 1.05, 2.25, 0.81],
   [4, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [8, 0.9, 2.25, 0.95],
   [9, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [12, 0.87, 2.25, 1.01],
   [14, 1, 2.25, 0.78],
   [17, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [19, 1.3, 2.5, 0.55],
   [22, 0.77, 2.25, 0.87],
   [23, 1.06, 2.25, 0.84],
   [24, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [31, 0.95, 2.25, 0.95],
   [35, 1.09, 2.25, 0.81],
   [42, 1.04, 2.25, 0.76],
   [49, 1.25, 2.5, 0.57]],
  'O_2247568': [[4, 3.1, 3.25, 2.3],
   [16, 2.85, 2.9, 2.3],
   [18, 3.25, 3.15, 2.2],
   [60, 3.1, 3.15, 2.32],
   [70, 3, 3.15, 2.35],
   [81, 3.3, 3, 2.38],
   [82, 3.1, 2.9, 2.2],
   [88, 3.2, 3, 2.25],
   [90, 2.9, 3.3, 2.32],
   [104, 3.1, 3.25, 2.25],
   [110, 3, 3.2, 2.4],
   [115, 3.4, 3, 2.25],
   [158, 2.95, 3.2, 2.35],
   [173, 3, 3, 2.25],
   [177, 3.08, 3.2, 2.49],
   [255, 3.2, 3.2, 2.25],
   [281, 2.9, 3.2, 2.38],
   [370, 2.75, 2.85, 2.05],
   [422, 3.2, 3.2, 2.25],
   [450, 3.05, 3.15, 2.28],
   [474, 2.82, 3.1, 2.48],
   [499, 3.1, 3.25, 2.23],
   [517, 3.25, 3.15, 2.2],
   [545, 3.1, 3.25, 2.23],
   [659, 3.12, 3.1, 2.18],
   [976, 3.3, 3.15, 2.2]],
  'L_2247568': [[3, 0.92, -0.25, 0.96],
   [8, 0.75, -0.25, 1.13],
   [12, 0.81, -0.25, 1.1],
   [14, 0.85, -0.25, 0.91],
   [17, 0.95, -0.25, 0.95],
   [19, 1.05, 0, 0.7],
   [22, 0.71, -0.25, 1],
   [23, 0.93, -0.25, 0.99],
   [24, 0.95, -0.25, 0.95],
   [31, 0.8, -0.25, 1.13],
   [35, 0.95, -0.25, 0.95],
   [42, 0.89, -0.25, 0.89]],
  'T_2247568': [[3, 1.05, 2.25, 0.81],
   [4, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [8, 0.98, 2.25, 0.88],
   [9, 1.3, 2.5, 0.57],
   [12, 1.01, 2.25, 0.87],
   [14, 1, 2.25, 0.78],
   [17, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [19, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [22, 0.85, 2.25, 0.8],
   [23, 1.06, 2.25, 0.84],
   [24, 1.08, 2.25, 0.8],
   [31, 1, 2.25, 0.9],
   [35, 1.09, 2.25, 0.81],
   [42, 1.04, 2.25, 0.76],
   [49, 1.25, 2.5, 0.57]],
  'O_2247569': [[4, 2.8, 2.95, 2.7],
   [16, 2.4, 2.8, 2.85],
   [18, 2.53, 3, 2.84],
   [60, 2.8, 2.9, 2.75],
   [70, 2.5, 2.95, 3],
   [81, 2.63, 3, 2.9],
   [82, 2.5, 2.87, 2.7],
   [88, 2.45, 2.9, 2.9],
   [90, 2.36, 3.1, 3],
   [104, 2.7, 3.05, 2.65],
   [110, 2.5, 3, 3.05],
   [115, 2.8, 2.9, 2.7],
   [158, 2.45, 3.1, 2.95],
   [173, 2.7, 2.75, 2.65],
   [177, 2.58, 3.12, 3.13],
   [255, 2.6, 3.2, 2.65],
   [281, 2.5, 3, 2.9],
   [370, 2.5, 2.6, 2.4],
   [422, 2.5, 3.1, 2.8],
   [450, 2.75, 2.9, 2.7],
   [474, 2.49, 2.94, 2.95],
   [499, 2.6, 3.15, 2.64],
   [517, 2.53, 3, 2.84],
   [545, 2.6, 3.15, 2.64],
   [659, 2.66, 3, 2.54],
   [976, 2.75, 3.05, 2.6]],
  'L_2247569': [[3, 0.93, 0, 0.95],
   [8, 0.73, 0, 1.15],
   [12, 0.74, 0, 1.19],
   [14, 0.78, 0, 1.08],
   [17, 1, 0, 0.9],
   [19, 0.7, 0, 1.05],
   [22, 0.69, 0, 1.03],
   [23, 0.94, 0, 0.98],
   [24, 1, 0, 0.9],
   [31, 0.8, 0, 1.13],
   [35, 1, 0, 0.9],
   [42, 0.94, 0, 0.84]],
  'T_2247569': [[3, 0.87, 2, 0.99],
   [4, 1.37, 2.5, 0.5],
   [8, 0.9, 2, 0.95],
   [9, 1.5, 2.5, 0.5],
   [12, 0.98, 2, 0.9],
   [14, 0.85, 2, 1],
   [17, 0.88, 2, 1],
   [19, 1.4, 2.5, 0.5],
   [22, 1.06, 2.25, 0.63],
   [23, 0.88, 2, 1.02],
   [24, 0.88, 2, 1],
   [31, 0.9, 2, 1],
   [35, 0.89, 2, 1.01],
   [42, 0.83, 2, 0.95],
   [49, 1.37, 2.5, 0.51]],
  'O_2247570': [[4, 3.4, 3.1, 2.2],
   [16, 3, 2.75, 2.35],
   [18, 3.3, 3.15, 2.18],
   [60, 3.4, 3.1, 2.2],
   [70, 3, 3, 2.45],
   [81, 3.4, 3.1, 2.3],
   [82, 3.1, 2.9, 2.2],
   [88, 3.2, 3, 2.25],
   [90, 2.8, 3.3, 2.34],
   [104, 3.35, 3.15, 2.2],
   [110, 3, 3.15, 2.45],
   [115, 3.4, 3.1, 2.2],
   [158, 2.9, 3.2, 2.37],
   [173, 3.3, 2.95, 2.13],
   [177, 3.23, 3, 2.53],
   [255, 3.2, 3.25, 2.2],
   [281, 2.9, 3.2, 2.38],
   [370, 3, 2.8, 1.95],
   [422, 3.2, 3.25, 2.2],
   [450, 3.38, 3.15, 2.16],
   [474, 2.82, 3.1, 2.48],
   [499, 3.15, 3.25, 2.19],
   [517, 3.3, 3.15, 2.18],
   [545, 3.15, 3.25, 2.19],
   [659, 3.2, 3.14, 2.12],
   [976, 3.35, 3.2, 2.15]],
  'L_2247570': [[3, 0.97, -0.25, 0.91],
   [8, 0.75, -0.25, 1.13],
   [12, 0.76, -0.25, 1.16],
   [14, 0.9, -0.25, 0.95],
   [17, 1, -0.25, 0.9],
   [19, 1.05, 0, 0.7],
   [22, 0.72, -0.25, 0.98],
   [23, 0.98, -0.25, 0.94],
   [24, 1, -0.25, 0.9],
   [31, 0.8, -0.25, 1.13],
   [35, 1, -0.25, 0.9],
   [42, 0.94, -0.25, 0.84]],
  'T_2247570': [[3, 1, 2.25, 0.86],
   [4, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [8, 0.95, 2.25, 0.9],
   [9, 1.25, 2.5, 0.6],
   [12, 0.95, 2.25, 0.93],
   [14, 0.98, 2.25, 0.85],
   [17, 1.03, 2.25, 0.85],
   [19, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6],
   [22, 0.81, 2.25, 0.83],
   [23, 1.01, 2.25, 0.89],
   [24, 1.03, 2.25, 0.85],
   [31, 1, 2.25, 0.9],
   [35, 1.04, 2.25, 0.86],
   [42, 0.98, 2.25, 0.81],
   [49, 1.2, 2.5, 0.6]],
  'O_2247571': [[4, 2.7, 3.1, 2.7],
   [16, 2.5, 2.75, 2.7],
   [18, 2.61, 3.15, 2.63],
   [60, 2.65, 3.15, 2.65],
   [70, 2.85, 2.88, 2.7],
   [81, 2.75, 3.1, 2.75],
   [82, 2.55, 3, 2.55],
   [88, 2.62, 3, 2.65],
   [90, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6],
   [104, 2.6, 3.3, 2.6],
   [110, 2.7, 3.1, 2.7],
   [115, 2.63, 3.2, 2.63],
   [158, 2.6, 3.1, 2.7],
   [173, 2.55, 3, 2.6],
   [177, 2.72, 2.99, 2.98],
   [255, 2.7, 2.95, 2.7],
   [281, 2.55, 3.2, 2.75],
   [370, 2.35, 2.85, 2.35],
   [422, 2.7, 2.95, 2.7],
   [450, 2.6, 3.15, 2.6],
   [474, 2.62, 3.1, 2.67],
   [499, 2.56, 3.35, 2.56],
   [517, 2.61, 3.15, 2.63],
   [545, 2.56, 3.35, 2.56],
   [659, 2.55, 3.16, 2.55],
   [976, 2.6, 3.2, 2.6]],
  'L_2247571': [[3, 0.94, 0, 0.94],
   [8, 0.85, 0, 1],
   [12, 0.93, 0, 0.97],
   [14, 0.91, 0, 0.93],
   [17, 0.95, 0, 0.95],
   [19, 0.8, 0, 0.9],
   [22, 1.15, 0.25, 0.61],
   [23, 0.95, 0, 0.97],
   [24, 0.95, 0, 0.95],
   [31, 0.94, 0, 0.98],
   [35, 0.95, 0, 0.95],
   [42, 0.89, 0, 0.89]],
  'T_2247571': [[3, 0.92, 2.25, 0.94],
   [4, 1.15, 2.5, 0.61],
   [8, 0.93, 2.25, 0.93],
   [9, 1.1, 2.5, 0.67],
   [12, 0.97, 2.25, 0.91],
   [14, 0.91, 2.25, 0.93],
   [17, 0.93, 2.25, 0.95],
   [19, 1.1, 2.5, 0.65],
   [22, 1.05, 2.5, 0.64],
   [23, 0.93, 2.25, 0.97],
   [24, 0.93, 2.25, 0.95],
   [31, 0.95, 2.25, 0.95],
   [35, 0.94, 2.25, 0.96],
   [42, 0.88, 2.25, 0.9],
   [49, 1.15, 2.5, 0.62]]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The response isn't in `json` format that's why the `response.json()` fails

we can use regular expressions to extract the data
and eval to convert string to list

```py
import re
import requests

params = {
    'sclassId': '40',
    'subSclassId': '261',
    'matchSeason': '2022-2023',
    'round': '23',
    'flesh': '0.6807624444063407',
}

response = requests.get('https://football.goaloo2.com/ajax/LeagueOddsAjax', params=params)

data = {}
for id_, lst in re.findall('oddsData\["(.+?)"\]=(.+?);', response.text):
    data[id_] = eval(lst)
```